# Topology - Projections

Tags: general-topology

I'm pretty sure I have this right, but want to double check and make sure.

Let $X_1$ = $X_2$ = $\mathbb{R}$ and let $p_1: X_1 \times X_2 \rightarrow X_1$ and $p_2: X_1 \times X_2 \rightarrow X_2$ be the projections.  Let $A = {(x,y): 1 \le x \le 2, 3 \le y \le 3x}$.  Find $p_1(A)$ and $p_2(A)$.

Answer?

$p_1(A)= [1,2]$

$p_2(A)= [3,6]$

Comment: Yes, those are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct.

Since $A=\{(x,y)\mid 1\le x\le2, 3\le y \le3x \}$, its projection $p_1(A)$ is a subset of $[1,2]$. On the other hand, for each $x\in[1,2]$ there is a $y\in[3,3x]$, so there is a point in $A$ which projects to $x$, thus $p_1(A)=[1,2]$

Since $3\le y\le3x\le6$, we have $p_2(A)\subseteq[3,6]$. And if $3\le y\le6$, then for $x=y/3$ the point $(x,y)\in A$ and projects to $y$, so $p_2(A)=[3,6]$